# Single Server with 3 network subnets - how to setup routing tables

Tags: networking, routing

I have 4 servers, each having 8 NICs each. For each server, 2 NICS form `bond0` (192.168.1.10; GW: 192.168.1.1), 2 NICS form `bond1` (192.168.2.10; GW 192.168.2.1) and 4 NICS form `bond2` (10.154.46.200; GW: 10.154.46.193). The subnets (`bond0`, `bond1`) are intended to support two different network attached storage devices (`bond0` to NAS1 on one subnet and `bond1` to NAS2 on the second subnet). The third subnet (`bond2`) goes out to an Intranet. `bond0` and `bond1` are on an internal 10GB network fabric with the NAS devices for speed of transferring data from the NAS devices to the servers. `bond2` is on a second 1GB (Intranet) network fabric for transferring data in/out of this server environment to external servers. There is no direct network link from the internal 10GB network and the 1GB Intranet network - two independent network fabrics. I have been able to establish the bond groups although I receive a warning that there is ambiguity for a default route. Besides the 2 NAS devices, the 4 servers all with the same NIC configuration (`bond0`, `bond1`, `bond2`) that need to be able to communicate with one another from say `server1`:192.168.1 subnet to `server2`:192.168.2 subnet and visa-versa. All the servers will also have access to the 10.154.46 subnet via `bond2`. The 192.168.* subnets both have respective gateways setup in the network switches. Not sure how I would setup routing tables for this such that the server knows what subnet to use when say data is written to a mount point of NAS1 (subnet1) versus NAS2 (subnet2)? I guess for server to server I can define multiple hostnames for the same server each with a different respective IP address? Not sure what my default route would be?

If I write data to NAS1 mount point that should go out over that subnet (192.168.1). If I write data to NAS2 mount point that should go over the other subnet (192.168.2). If I reach out to an external machine on the Intranet it should go over the 10.154.46 subnet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you running a supported Ubuntu release?Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 20.04. I am using Netplan to setup the bond pairs which works fine. I am just not sure what I need to setup as far as routing tables go to get the effect I described. The Netplan examples are not all that helpful for my situation.